# React : Warning: Failed prop type: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am working on a navbar in react and i have been getting this error, and i have not found a working solution yet. Here is the piece of my code. I am trying to use react prop-types library to validate my navbar props with either a link or a dropdown. Below is the piece of code i have written.

NavBar.js

```
const NavBar = ({ navItems }) => {
return (
    <nav role="navigation" className={styles.navBar}>
        <Logo type="text">
            ABCD
        </Logo>
        <div className={[styles.collapse, styles.noCollapse].join(' ')}>
            <SearchBox />
            <NavItems navItemsData={navItems} />
        </div>
    </nav>
);
};
```

NavItems.js

```
const NavItems = ({ navItemsData }) => {
return (
    <ul className={styles.navItems}>
        {navItemsData.map(navItemData => {
            let navItem = <NavItem {...navItemData} key={navItemData.id} />
            if (navItemData.type === 'dropdown') {
                navItem = <NavDropDownItem {...navItemData} key={navItemData.id} />
            }
            return navItem;
        })}
    </ul>
);
};
```

PropTypes Checker(in same file as NavItems) :-

```
NavItems.propTypes = {
navItemsData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id : PropTypes.number,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(['link', 'dropdown']).isRequired,
    linkText: requiredIf(PropTypes.string.isRequired, props => props.type === 'link'),
    title : requiredIf(PropTypes.string.isRequired, props => props.type === 'dropdown'),
    dropDownList: requiredIf(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ linkText: PropTypes.string.isRequired })), props => props.type === 'dropdown')
}))
};
```

I keep getting this warning in the console. As follows :-

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    in NavItems (at NavBar.js:15)
    in NavBar (at App.js:35)
    in div (at App.js:34)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

The props i am passing :

```
const navItems = [{
    id : 1,
    type : 'link',
    linkText : 'Link1'
  },{
    id : 2,
    type : 'link',
    linkText : 'Link2'
  }, {
    id : 3,
    type : 'link',
    linkText : 'Link3'
  }, {
    id : 4,
    type : 'link',
    linkText : 'Link4'
  },{
    id : 5,
    type : 'link',
    linkText : 'Link5'
  },{
    id : 6,
    type : 'dropdown',
    dropDownList : [{
      linkText : 'LinkText'
    }]
  }]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `requiredIf` uses [apply](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-required-if/blob/master/index.js#L16) so that might narrow the issue down for you. It maybe that `dropDownList` entry in the proptypes. Try commenting that out and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in code sanbox ?

Comment: @uneet7 Please find the codesandbox : [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-diffie-48mim)

Check the console window of codesandbox on refresh.

Comment: @andy i have tried commenting. but it doesnt work. i have made a codesandbox with similar code. Its just above this comment. Please check. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `requiredIf`, the first parameter should be the expected type. But it should not have the `isRequired` part. For example, your validation should be as follows.

```
NavItems.propTypes = {
    navItemsData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      id : PropTypes.number,
      type: PropTypes.oneOf(['link', 'dropdown']).isRequired,
      linkText: requiredIf(PropTypes.string, props => props.type === 'link'),
      title : requiredIf(PropTypes.string, props => props.type === 'dropdown'),
      dropDownList: requiredIf(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ linkText: PropTypes.string.isRequired })), props => props.type === 'dropdown')
}))};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do `PropTypes.string.isRequired` inside `requiredIf` as it already covers the required case.

[image: Edit goofy-rain-6bx03]

```
NavItems.propTypes = {
  navItemsData: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      type: PropTypes.oneOf(["link", "dropdown"]).isRequired,
      linkText: requiredIf(PropTypes.string, props => props.type === "link"),
      title: requiredIf(PropTypes.string, props => props.type === "dropdown"),
      dropDownList: requiredIf(
        PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ linkText: PropTypes.string })),
        props => props.type === "dropdown"
      )
    })
  )
};
```